# Which directory should I place my json file, in order to import it into couchdb

Tags: json, curl, couchdb

I'm new to CouchDB, I have successfully installed and i'm able to use curl to create a database.

However I want to import a json file to the database.

This is what I have done.

```
C:\Users\*****>curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/mydatabase
{"ok":true}
```

But when I try to import a json file, I get this error

> C:\Users*****>curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/mydatabase \ -H
>   'Content-Type: application/json' -d @q2.json Warning: Couldn't read
>   data from file "q2.json", this makes an empty POST.
>   {"error":"bad_content_type","reason":"Content-Type must be
>   application/json"} curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \ curl: (6) Could
>   not resolve host: application

My question is, in which directory should I place my json file ?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with couchDB but with curl and running commands from the command line.

I think that the file should be in the same folder as you're running the curl command from (since you're addressing it as q2.json).

And I don't think the \ inside your curl command is helping you eighter, try it without.

To add a document to couchDB you need to give it an ID, your curl should look something like this:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/mydatabase/foo -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @q2.json
```

Comment: My curl.exe is located inside my windows folder.                                      I added the q1.json file inside the windows folder ,but i still get this error                          C:\Users\DELL>curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/mydatabase/foo -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @q1.json
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "q1.json", this makes an empty POST.
`{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Referer header required."}`
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application

Comment: I finally got it. I just needed to specify the document path. Like this                      C:\Users\DELL>curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/africanproverbs/foo1 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @"C:/Users/DELL/Downloads/couch/json/q3.json"
{"ok":true,"id":"foo1","rev":"1-afb0f36f8b1fd27c0585919747f14c57"}
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application